.NET 8 Console app - HostApplicationBuilder - how to access services after in app
I have a .NET 8 console application that is using HostApplicationBuilder to set up and configure a Windows service.
Does anyone know how one can access the IServiceCollection within the IHost object once the application is running?
I've added an Entity Framework Core DbContext (AddDbContext), a Windows service (AddSingleton) and a background worker (AddHostedService).
I then call host.Run() which fires the background worker's ExecuteAsync() method.
Within the background worker, the constructor is passed the service and within ExecuteAsync(), I can call methods on that service.
However, the issue is that I need to be able to retrieve the database context (it is not part of the service as this does something else) - but there is no handle back to the IHost object.
I am kind of looking at doing something like (where xyz is the reference to the services)
xyz.GetService("myservice").DoSomething()

or
xyz.GetContext("bobsContext").UpdateSomething()

Much of the documentation I have found assumes web applications and the scaffolding from one of the Visual Studio web templates, however, I am working on a Windows Service.
UPDATE:
After investigation, I found that host.Run() which executes in a static main will execute until the injected worker (AddHostedService) terminates. However, the worker does not have a reference to the host so cannot call GetService() to retrieve the other injected items.
My current solution was to create a custom HostApplicationBuilder (e.g. MyHostBuilder) as a singleton. I can access this from inside the worker and then pull the services back.

You could inject an IDbContextFactory in the constructor, just like you inject your service:
public class MyWorker: BackgroundService
{
  public MyWorker(
    IMyService myService, 
    IDbContextFactory<BobsContext> contextFactory)
  { //...
  }

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(...)
  {
    // Create new context from the factory
    using (var bobsContext = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        bobsContext.UpdateSomething();
    }

    myService.DoSomething();

  }
}

Alternatively, if you really need to resolve any registered service, you could inject a whole IServiceProvider and either do a GetService<>() on it, or do it inside a CreateScope() like they do in the link (your DbContext likely requires a scope, and your singleton service doesn't).

Thanks for the reply. This is what the default code does, except I inject a service as it is a windows service.  From the service I cannot access the rest of the items loaded into host.services - hence my question.  The code needs to be extensible - so imagine there are more services and contexts.

That should be what the link in the last paragraph shows, using the IServiceProvider. Just inject it to wherever you need it. Inject it to your service, your BackgroundService, anywhere. And then just call GetService<whatever>() from the IServiceProvider.

I updated my original post with a work-a-round for the moment.

SETUP
First, when you create host, you need to configure it, just as you would in ASP.NET application. So you specify where the config lies, what are dependency injected services:
IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            // Here you need to specify where you have your
            // connection string and other configuration for
            // application.
            config
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json");
        })
        // Here you need to define all services that you would
        // like to be dependency injected into constructors.
        // One of them is our DbContext which is registered 
        // with AddSqlServer (or equivalent method for other
        // RDBMS providers).
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSqlServer<ExampleWebApiContext>(
                hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleWebApiContext"));
            services.AddScoped<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
        });

I defined IMyRepository interface which will use DbContext for complete example:
public interface IMyRepository
{
    Task<Movie[]> GetMoviesAsync();
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly ExampleWebApiContext _context;

    public MyRepository(ExampleWebApiContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Movie[]> GetMoviesAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Movies.ToArrayAsync();
    }
}

RUNNING PROGRAM
Our application's main code becomes now very simple and we are able to resolve any registered service:
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
var myRepo = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyRepository>();
var movies = await myRepo.GetMoviesAsync();

If you want to work with DbContext directly, you can always get it like below:
var dbContext = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ExampleWebApiContext>();


Thanks, I have all of the infrastructure (setup) code working fine. However, I note you still have access to the host variable and are calling host.services.   In my case, it is a windows service and I am operating after host.run().

@AndyW You can invoke host.Run() with my code. It's perfectly fine. I just ommited it in my example, as it was not relevant there.

Thanks, but it is actually after the host.Run() that the issue occurs.  In the end I wrote a custom HostApplicationBuilder that runs as a Singleton and provides access to the host object.  If I can  find the time I will post it as a solution - I may also mark yours as a solution as well as I think they both overlap a little.
